# How do I link NLTK in Jupyter on a mac?

Tags: python, macos, nltk

I have already downloaded NLTK but Jupyter Notebook still shows:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'`

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, you could have several version of Python.

First, if you're using a virtual environment, activate it and then, try this:

```
pip install nltk
```

or with Python 3:

```
pip3 install nltk
```

Comment: I got this:
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (2020.7.14)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (4.48.0)

Comment: If you're using a virtual environment, try to activate it first and then use: `pip install nltk`

Comment: Are you actually using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the python installation used by your Jupyter Notebook is different.
To check this

Run below command from Jupyter Notebook

```
!which python
```

and below command from terminal

```
which python
```

If they are different then you are sure that python installation used by your Jupyter Notebook is different

Now run below command from Jupyter Notebook to install NLTK

```
!pip install nltk
```

#### Or

Just check if nltk is installed in the python site-packages used by Jupyter Notebook by running below command from Notebook

```
!pip list|grep nltk
```

If you dont see anything then it mean nltk you have to different python installation and the one used by jpyter does not have Nltk installed. So install it by running the below command from Jupyter Notebook

```
!pip install nltk
```

Comment: Thank you very much!      I did as u told and got this. i checked if the version was the same and yes it is.          
!pip list|grep nltk
nltk       3.5
In [6]:

import nltk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1d2184025e54> in <module>
----> 1 import nltk

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'